# Not able to deploy Amazon S3 connector amazons3-connector-2.0.2 in wso2 ei 6.6.0

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

***Issue Description***

I am connecting to amazon S3 to download files using amazons3-connector-2.0.2.
This setup totally works fine in Integration Studio 8.0.1 but when I deploy the car file to WSO2 EI 6.6.0 RHEL 8 Linux Box it gives error.

**Below is the Error Snippet :**

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-09-21 05:42:11,127] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ClassMediatorFactory} - Error in instantiating class : org.wso2.carbon.connector.amazons3.operations.S3Config java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/connector/core/connection/Connection
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ClassMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(ClassMediatorFactory.java:110)
    .....
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Not found : org.wso2.carbon.connector.core.connection.Connection
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader.findClass(DeploymentClassLoader.java:95)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader.loadClass(DeploymentClassLoader.java:276)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 73 more
```

Answer (score 1):

We have made some improvements to the connector core and shipped these changes as an update for EI 6.6.0. As a result, this issue is observed in the EI 6.6.0 base pack. Therefore you will need to update the EI pack to the latest version to use the amazons3-connector-2.0.2. You may refer to the following docs to update the product,

- WUM updates - https://docs.wso2.com/display/updates100/Getting+Started
- U2 updates(recommended) - https://updates.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/updates/migrating-to-updates2.0/

Integration Studio 8.0.1, use MI 4.0.0(which already has these improvements) as the in-built runtime. That's why you won't observe these errors in the Integration Studio.

Comment: Is this fix available for open source or only for licensed version of wso2.

Comment: You need to have a WSO2 subscription to get WSO2 updates. You can try a trial subscription for 90 days. Please refer https://updates.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/updates/overview/#how-to-get-wso2-updates